# Add expandable UITextView cell to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have collection view when one of it's cell is cell that contain `UITextView`. What i want is to add `textView` to this cell that will expand accordingly to entered text.

I created UIView that have text view inside:

```
private var textView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.isEditable = true
    return textView
  }()
```

Inside i set up it's constraints to superview as following:

```
private func setConstraints() {
  let width: CGFloat = 312
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
}
```

Then inside cell i set constraints like that:

```
func setConstraints() {
textView.topAnchor.equalTo(topAnchor).isActive = true
textView.leftAnchor.equalTo(leftAnchor).isActive = true
textView.rightAnchor.equalTo(rightAnchor).isActive = true
textView.bottomAnchor.equalTo(bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I did achieve behaviour when cell is expanding after textView growth, but, i didn't set bottom constraint for UITextView->UIView, that why my collection view doesn't grow (scroll) when i type large bunch of text in my cell.
How to add cell with UITextView inside that will expand CollectionView it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to use manual estimation text view height and return one in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

This approach is more difficult than using AutoLayout but gives more control and customization possibilities.